# How to change animations every 60 seconds through the animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made several animations on a character through the animator in Unity.

And I added a countdown timer which is a Text Ui component from a canvas. It is initially 00, but when I play the start button it decrease from 60 by 1 to 0, during which time animation1 repeats. When the timer reaches 0 I want the animation to change, so from animation1 to enter animation2.

[image: Timer Code]

Above is the code for the timer and the if condition where I managed to do this with a bolean parameter from animator and an if condition in a C # script.

But when the timer ran out a second time and reached 0 I want it to go from 'animation2' to 'animation3' and  the parameter 'change' to become false and the parameter 'change1' to become true. And so, every time the timer reaches 0 another animation to load.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

In general: Post code as **text**, NOT as images!

---

Instead of using a `Bool` animator parameter and

```
animator.SetBool("change", true");
```

rather use a Trigger parameter and

```
animator.SetTrigger("change");
```

A Trigger is reset at the same time it is consumed by the transition.

Then simply set up your animation transitions like

```
animation1 --- Condition: Change(Trigger) ---> animation2
animation2 --- Condition: Change(Trigger> ---> animation3
...
```